# How to remove subdirectories inserted into the dired buffer with i?

Tags: dired

Pressing `i` on a subdirectory in the dired mode inserts that directory in the buffer. How can I remove it from the buffer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Type <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> on the subdirectory header line.

Quoth [`(emacs) Subdirectories in Dired`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Subdirectories-in-Dired.html):

```
   Use the ‘l’ command (‘dired-do-redisplay’) to update the
subdirectory’s contents, and use ‘C-u k’ on the subdirectory header line
to remove the subdirectory listing (see Dired Updating).  You can
also hide and show inserted subdirectories (see Hiding
Subdirectories).
```

and [`(emacs) Dired Updating`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Updating.html):

```
   If you use ‘k’ to kill the line for a directory file which you had
inserted in the Dired buffer as a subdirectory (see Subdirectories in
Dired), it removes the subdirectory listing as well.  Typing ‘C-u k’
on the header line for a subdirectory also removes the subdirectory line
from the Dired buffer.
```

and [`(emacs) Hiding Subdirectories`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hiding-Subdirectories.html):

```
“Hiding” a subdirectory means to make it invisible, except for its
header line.

‘$’
     Hide or show the subdirectory that point is in, and move point to
     the next subdirectory (‘dired-hide-subdir’).  This is a toggle.  A
     numeric argument serves as a repeat count.
```

How I navigated the manual:

1. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> (`info-emacs-manual`)
2. <kbd>i</kbd> (`Info-index`)
3. `subdir`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> (autocompletes to `subdirectories in Dired`)